# My script produces illegible output in a csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping

When I run my script I get desired output in the console but when I write the same in a csv file, the output becomes illegible. I tried with `encoding="utf-8"` but no luck, still the same.

[sitelink](http://www.english-bangla.com/browse/bntobn/)

These are the portion of content I'm willing to write in a csv file.

`অ অংশ অংশ অংশাংশি`.

I've written so far:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.english-bangla.com/browse/bntobn/"

def get_links(link):
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    items = [item.text for item in soup.select("#cat_page ul > li > a")]
    return items

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("output.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for item in get_links(url):
            writer.writerow(item)
```

> How can I write the content in a csv file in the right way?

Comment: maybe context is correct but you display CSV in tool which doesn't work with UTF-8 or doesn't have font to display it. Did you try to read CSV in python and display from python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`writerow()` needs list of elements, not single element.
And then it put every element in separated column (using comma)

```
with open("output.csv","w", newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(get_links(url))
```

If you put single element - string - then it treats it as list of chars
and it put every char in separated column - so you have comma between chars.

Comment: I tried your suggestion as well but the content I get written in a csv file are like `à¦… à¦…à¦‚à¦¶ à¦…à¦‚à¦¶ à¦…à¦‚à¦¶à¦¾à¦‚à¦¶à¦¿ à¦…à¦‚à¦¶à¦¾à¦¨.
`

Comment: How do you checked this ? As I said in comment above - problem can be tool which you use to display it. I used your code and opened file in Linux text  editor Pluma and I see it correctly.

Comment: To walk you through - I execute the code in sublime text. Once the execution is finished, I get a data-ridden csv output in the directory. I open it manually and the above is the output I see in that csv file. Is there still any room for cofusion as to how I open that? Feel free to ask. Thanks.

Comment: read csv to python and display from python. ie, `print(open("output.csv").read())`

Comment: That gives me the right output. In other cases I see the displayed content as desired no matter how I open a csv file? Can I not see the desired content in that csv file when I open manually?

Comment: use tool which works with "utf-8". It seems you use tool which doesn't respect "utf-8" and it display it as normal ascii. Or use like LibreOffice, OpenOffice, Microsoft Office to open CSV.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer for the clarity of things.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is your problem:

```
writer.writerow(item)
```

The `writerow` method expects a sequence of items, where each item corresponds to a column in your csv file.  Your normally would call it with some sort of iterable, such as a list.  For example:

```
writer.writerow(['one', 'two', 'three'])
```

Would generate an entry in your csv file that looked like:

```
one,two,three
```

In Python, a string also happens to be an iterable.  Compare this, in which we pass a list of one item:

```
writer.writerow(['this is a test'])
```

With this, in which we pass a string:

```
writer.writerow('this is a test')
```

The former will result in:

```
this is a test
```

The latter will result in:

```
t,h,i,s, ,i,s, ,a, ,t,e,s,t
```

So you probably want to write your main block like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("output.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for item in get_links(url):
            writer.writerow([item])
```

Or, as @furas suggested, just get rid of the `for` loop:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("output.csv","w",newline="",encoding="utf-8") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(get_links(url))
```

Both solutions get you to the same place. The second is more efficient.

This will result in a csv file that looks like:

```
অ
অংশ
অংশ
অংশাংশি
অংশান
.
.
.
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion @larsks. This is what I get as output in the csv file `à¦…
à¦…à¦‚à¦¶
à¦…à¦‚à¦¶
à¦…à¦‚à¦¶à¦¾à¦‚à¦¶à¦¿
à¦…à¦‚à¦¶à¦¾à¦¨
à¦…à¦‚à¦¶à¦¿à¦¨à§â€Œ
à¦…à¦‚à¦¶à§
à¦…à¦‚à¦¶à§¨
`

Comment: That's not what I see when I run the same code, using Python 3.6.8. The output I've shown in the answer is a direct extract from the generated output. What are you using to inspect the csv file?

Comment: I directly opened the csv file manually and copied the content in order to paste here. I'm using python 3.7+.

Comment: Nope, the second is not efficient as they display the content in a single row which is not i'm expecting. I will stick to your solution but the output is not desirable yet.